# MS Teams Personal tabs Apps can have subtabs/submenus in it?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is that possible to add child tabs(similar to sub-menus) to a Personal Tab Apps in MS Teams? If not, is there any workaround to achieve this.
Please note we have used the App studio to build the app not the custom code.
(refer screenshot below)?

[image: Expectation]

Comment: I've the same ask. I raised it as a request in the Microsoft community here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1d4a97d2-a87e-ec11-a81b-6045bd7bf64c

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that in the main tab infrastructure, but -inside- your tab you could build whatever you like - it's just a normal web page. You could tabs, menus, etc. For instance, see how Planner has it's own top menu in the first screenshot over here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/planner-blog/microsoft-teams-in-microsoft-365-government-gcc-now-includes/ba-p/360089

Comment: I've been looking for the a solution to the same problem. I think it's a fair ask. The manifest file already defines the tabs and the URL's for their embedded apps, so being able to create subtabs there as well is a reasonable request. For us at least, having to build a subnavigation component just for Teams, not used in our normal web app, is unwanted overhead.

Comment: @Hilton_Giesenow FYI I've raised this as feedback here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1d4a97d2-a87e-ec11-a81b-6045bd7bf64c

Comment: ok great - if you feel strongly about it, good that you've logged it with Microsoft. Personally, I don't see this as a problem - Microsoft's giving you the surface, via a Tab, to plug your custom solution into Teams, but it's a totally blank slate. You can choose to put whatever you want in your web app, navigation or otherwise. You're also free to choose to make it look 'like Teams' or however else you choose. You don't say whether this is an internal app or something you're wanting to put in the store, but if it's internal do whatever you like. In the store there are some stricter rules.